# Rust: Async find (use await within predicate)

Tags: rust

I am trying to use async within find predicates.
We can use the find method to look up an element within an iterator as follows:

```
let element = some_elements.iter().find(|element| {
  // some_async_method(element).await;
  // true or false based on some logic
});
```

In my case, I need to call async methods as a part of my lookup logic. However, when I use await, I end up with the error that await cannot be called within non-async block, which is expected. When I try to make my function async as follows:

```
let element = some_elements.iter().find(|element| async move{
  // some_async_method(element).await;
  // true or false based on some logic
});
```

I get the error: expected `bool`, found opaque type

I tried to to use rayon, but could not find an example for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `futures::stream::iter` to turn your iterator into a `Stream`.

Since `find` is not implemented on `StreamExt` I replaced it with `filter().next()` in the following:

```rust
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
//…
let element = futures::stream::iter(&some_elements)
    .filter(|e| Box::pin(async move { predicate(e).await }))
    .next()
    .await;
```

If you actually want to do your work asynchronously though you'd have to be a little more verbose and collect into a `FuturesOrdered`/`FuturesUnordered` depending on your actual requirements:

```rust
let element = some_elements
    .iter()
    .map(|&e| async move { (predicate(e).await, e) })
    .collect::<FuturesUnordered<_>>()
    .filter_map(|(p, e)| Box::pin(async move { p.then_some(e) }))
    .next()
    .await;
```